# Java interface: default method without implementation

Tags: java, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

I bumped into this class (in org.springframework.web.socket). I was surprised to see an interface with default methods WITHOUT implementation. What is the purpose of doing so ?
[image]

My understanding is that an interface is kind of a contract. We can expect that the implementing classes implements each method of the interface (or uses the default implementation provided by the interface in case of default method). But in case of default method without implementation, we could have implementing classes with methods doing nothing. Isn't it a break of the interface contract (and at the same time of Liskov substitution principle) ?

Comment: Why can't "do nothing" be a kind of implementation?

Comment: This is so you can implement this interface by your own class and provide implementations of only the specific methods you want. Previously this pattern would be achieved by having an interface and an abstract class that had all those empty methods, and you would extend the abstract class. Now since Java 8, you can cut out the abstract class.

Comment: A real example is a method doMakeUpBeforeGoingOut() in the interface Humain, it can be an empty method by default , and if you need to impelement it for example with Women class you can do , with the class Men it will still use the empty method implementation inhereted from the interface. the call will be the same with no need to use if x instance of Men / if x instance of Women.